# rails callbacks not getting executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

For my life I trying to find out why are my callbacks are not getting executed `sometimes`(you heard it right **sometimes** as most of time it works out of the box)

All I have is parent/child relations between 2 models

upon creation of child record all I'm doing in `after_create` callback  is update(accumulate all child amount in parent field to avoid heavy query at run time) the amount field in parent table/ model record

Parent model(`Payout`)

Child model is (`Sales Transaction`)

`Payout` **has_many** `SalesTransactions` as said above upon creation of sales transaction I'm updating(incrementing to be precise) the `amount` field of parent record (payout record) so as to avoid heavy query at run time.

so Payout `amount field` is nothing but summation of all amount of the  `sales_transactions` of that payouts

it as good as saying as payout.amount would be(after callback is executed)

`payout.amount == payout.sales_transactions.pluck('amount').sum`

and that what I trying to achieve using callbacks

```
class SalesTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :payout
   after_create :update_payout_for_sale

   def update_payout_for_sale
    sales_amount = payout.amount || 0
    sales_amount =  sales_amount + amount.to_f
    ## Also make note of the minus from original amount i.e refund and custom_deduction_amount
    payout.update_attributes(:amount => sales_amount)
  end  

end

class Payout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales_transactions
  has_one :referrer
  after_save :update_referrer_earning

  def update_referrer_earning
    referrer.update_attributes(:amount  => (amount*10)/100.to_d)) rescue nil
  end
end
```

The interesting part over here is that `sometime` when SalesTransaction is `created` the callback is just not called as I dont see the update value of the in payouts record

I'm trying to avoid the callback for now but for the sake knowing `why` the callback is not getting executed has `led me` to ask this question

### NOTE

1. There is not Validation neither on SalesTransaction and Payout table ( I have check this 1000 times)
   `Payout.validators` => []

   `SalesTransaction.validators` => []
2. There is no mass asssignment issue as I havent define `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` (I Check this as well and also as said it work most time which wouldn't have been the case with mass-assignment warning)
3. SalesTransaction record is getting created all the time only the payouts record is not getting update(`sometime`)
4. I have removed most of the unwanted(over here) associations from `sales_transactions` and `payouts`
   for code brevity
5. No there isnt any thing like `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on either of the models
6. No dynamic validations attached ,extra, extra

Lastly Here how I'm trying to create the `SalesTransaction`

```
  options =  {"performer_id"=>177, "customer_id"=>35526, "sale_type"=>"sale", "show_id"=>502, "performer_percentage"=>BigDecimal.new("40.0"), "show_duration"=>4104, "gross_credits"=>3754, "gross_sales"=>BigDecimal.new("375.4"), "amount"=>BigDecimal.new("150.16"), "affiliate_id"=>nil, "affiliate_earning"=>BigDecimal.new("0.0"), "total_profit"=>BigDecimal.new("225.24"), "payout_period_id"=>89,"payout_id"=>4156, "stream_connection_id"=>540572, "history_id"=>44575, "credits"=>{:when_show_started=>350, :purchased_during_show=>{:free=>[], :paid=>[]}, :total_consumed=>{:free=>350, :paid=>3754}}, "sliding_scale_recalculations_done"=>false, "paid_minutes"=>62.57}
```

`SalesTransaction.create(options)`

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is the Payout class doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. Also, I'm confused about NOTE #2. Did you disable whitelisting attributes in your application.rb file which is why you aren't using attr_accessible? Otherwise that list of attributes needs to be defined. Assuming those two questions aren't the culprit, this should work as I just tested it.

Comment: @Keith my apologizes typo error correcting it

Comment: @Keith With regards to whitelisting as I mention I havent define any anything `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` in Payout Model also as mention in the same point `#2` that it was a case of mass-assignment it would have fail `all the time` and not `sometime`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave a comment in response to Viren.  Try `SalesTransaction.create!` (with the exclamation mark).  Do you then see the mass-assignment error consistently?

Comment: nope the sales transaction records is getting created only the payouts column `update` is not functioning `sometimes` I have checked for mass-assignment in payouts model as well

Answer (score 0):

Try after_save instead of after_create.