# Trigger in mysql complain

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

This is refrence to my earlier question

[rails callbacks not getting executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955052/rails-callbacks-not-getting-executed)

Now since the framework is not working some time I rather thinking of writing a trigger to do this

so my trigger look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sales_earning AFTER INSERT ON sales_transactions  FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
   DECLARE earning INT;
   SET earning = (select sales_earning from payouts where id = NEW.payout_id);
   earning = earning + NEW.amount   
   UPDATE payouts SET sales_earning = earning where id = NEW.payout_id ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Anyone has a clue as what the issue is with the trigger It complaining

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= earning + NEW.amount ;

FYI there is parent - child relationship between payouts and sales_transactions

Any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER sales_earning AFTER INSERT ON sales_transactions FOR EACH ROW  
  UPDATE payouts
  SET    sales_earning = sales_earning + NEW.amount
  WHERE  id = NEW.payout_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after `earning = earning + NEW.amount`

And you should do:

```
SET earning = (select sales_earning from payouts where id = NEW.payout_id) + NEW.amount;
```

UPDATE:

My answer points to what is wrong with your trigger, but if that's all you want to do with earnings, you should simply do it like eggyal's answer is pointing out